# Query to get price from one record and date from another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my code:

```
select row_number() over (order by cte3.update desc) as row_num,

            (select cte3.update from last_two_items 
             where idOrder = 1 and 
             cte3.toy_id = toy_id
            ) as update,

            cte3.price_previous as price_previous,
            cte3.price_current as price_current,
            cte3.id as id,
            cte3.toy_id as toy_id

    from last_two_items as cte3
    where idOrder = 2
```

I have a temporary table called last_two_items. This temporary table has a few columns: old price, new price, date of update, idOrder etc.

It looks like this:

```
old_price   new_price    date of update             idOrder         toy_id
0           0.16         2013-08-06 10:03:41.700    1               123
0.16        0.08         2013-08-06 10:02:28.850    2               123
```

As a result from my query I want to get the old price and the new price from the record where idOrder  is 2, but the date of update from the record where idOrder = 1. The toy is the same for both of the records.

However, with the code I have (the code from the beginning of this question), I only get the record with idOrder = 2.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't give a correct label to your table and this make some confusion. Try this:

```
select row_number() over (order by cte3.update desc) as row_num,

        (select innerQuery.update from last_two_items as innerQuery
         where innerQuery.idOrder = 1 and 
         innerQuery.toy_id = cte3.toy_id
        ) as update,

        cte3.price_previous as price_previous,
        cte3.price_current as price_current,
        cte3.id as id,
        cte3.toy_id as toy_id

from last_two_items as cte3
where idOrder = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite it's working I'd suggest to use other approach:

```
select lti2.old_price, lti2.new_price, lti1.date_of_update
from last_two_items lti1
left join last_two_items lti2
where lti1.idOrder = 1 and lti2.idOrder = 2
```

Fairly easy thing without sub-selects.